# How to make a variable in Objective C a single assignment variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I am using a global string variable (declaring it in the main and reusing it in different classes) in an iOS project and i want to make sure that once I assign a value to it it can never be reassigned. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use GCD for this:

```
static float value = 0.f;

+ (void)setValue:(float)_value
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        value = _value;
    });
}
```

That way the assignment can just be done once.

Answer (score 1):

You **couldn't** do with this in **main**.m. Because application start with main.m, you can't find main.h which is abstract.

It could be done with following steps.

1) define global static property in CommonConstant.h

```
static NSString *common;
```

2) Import this file in YourApp-prefix.pch file to visible globally.

```
#import "CommonConstant.h"
```

3) Then assign with GCD concept in your different classes which will make point to first assign even happen more assignment.

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    // Do the variable assignment here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it constant

```
const int no = 10;
```

or you can also make it macro

```
#define myConstant 1
```

and access it in other class simply importing the class where you define this macro.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to reuse in different classes you can put

```
#define myConstVariable 10
```

in the pre-compiled header file (`.pch`). The pre-compiled header file (`.pch`) is compiled and including automatically in all of your header files (`.h`) so it will be seen globally throughout your project.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `NSObject` subclass and call it `Constants`

Constants.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Constants : NSObject

extern NSString * const MyStringConstant;

@end
```

Constants.m:

```
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation Constants

NSString * const MyStringConstant = @"ValueOfMyStringConstant";

@end
```

And to reach it from every class you can import it in to the `pch` file like this

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "Constants.h"
#endif
```